# How to display countdown timer data in a text object across multiple scenes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When the player dies, one health indicator is disabled and a countdown timer starts, lasting for 5 minutes and then the indicator activates again.

How do I display the timer across different scenes, so that the player have an indicator to see when he has lifes again to retry? Is there a way to find a new text object when the scene reloads or change to a different scene?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TimerText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static TimerText instance;

    private Text timeText;

    [SerializeField]
    public GameObject heart;

    private float time;

    private void Awake()
    {
        MakeSingleton();
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        timeText = GameObject.Find("/Canvas/Resource_Life/Resource_Base /Timer").GetComponent<Text>(); ;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {            
        if(heart.activeSelf == false && timeText.text == "<color=white>00:00</color>")
        {
            StartCoundownTimer();
        }
    }

    public void MakeSingleton()
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
    }

    void StartCoundownTimer()
    {
        if (timeText != null)
        {
            time = 300;
            timeText.text = "00:00";
            InvokeRepeating("UpdateTimer", 0.0f, 0.01667f);
        }
    }

    void UpdateTimer()
    {
        if (timeText != null)
        {
            time -= Time.deltaTime;
            string minutes = Mathf.Floor(time / 60).ToString("00");
            string seconds = (time % 60).ToString("00");
            timeText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;
            if (minutes == "00" && seconds == "00") 
            {
                heart.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The countdown timer should continue and be shown in the new text object that is created if the scene is reloaded or changed, instead of giving the error "GameObject has been destroyed".

Comment: Got it to work, don't know if there is another way. I just moved the code from start to update,

Comment: You should wrap it with an `if(!timeText ) { ... }` otherwise it is very inefficient!

Comment: @ derHugo Thanks for your reply. I did as you said and placed the original line back in start also.